# Parse Mutual Friends response PHP JSON

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api to access mutual friend list using PHP
Here's how I am doing it

```
$url  = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/mutualfriends/123456788?access_token=1457856";

$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonurl));
```

I am now printing the result via print_r($user->data) and following is the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => XYZ
            [id] => 123
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => YZX
            [id] => 235
        )

)
```

I need to get name and Id of the mutual friends from the above resultset using PHP

What should be the next step for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be the same like `$user->data`:

```
foreach($user->data as $user) {
   echo "name: ".$user->name."<br>";
   echo "id: ".$user->id."<hr>";
}
```

---

I have tested this on the following data:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => ID
                    [name] => Name
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => ID
                    [name] => Name
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I am not getting the desired output with this code, here's how I have implemented it

Comment: foreach($user->data as $resultSet)
{
echo $resultSet->name;
}

Comment: FYI: mutual friends API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher 
(in case anyone tries this in 2017)